# How to stop tasks at specific time using systemd

Tags: linux, bash, systemd

I have script that is executed when system starts. I would like to use `at` or something else to stop the script (processes spammed by this script) at specific time. I tried to write something like this, but it seems it doesn't work

audio.service

```bash
[Unit] 
Description=Audio service
After=multi-user.target

[Service] 
Restart=always 
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/suomi/scripts/audio.sh && /usr/bin/at 15:26 pkill pulseaudio && systemctl stop audio.service
User=suomi
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/suomi/.Xauthority

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Do you want to stop it once? Or every day when the machine is up and this time happen?

Comment: @RomeoNinov every day when the machine is up please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For job run on boot of the system you can use command:

```
@reboot sleep 300 && systemctl stop daemon
```

and add it in `root` `cron` with command

```
crontab -e
```

P.S. Hope 300 seconds are enough to get system up and running. In case of need increase the time